# Teradata to Hive table importTool using Teradata connector

Tags: hadoop, import, hive

I am using TDCH for importing TD table to Hive.

using below command:-
    hadoop jar teradata-connector-1.3.4.jar   com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool -url jdbc:teradata://URL -username **** -password ****** -jobtype hive -fileformat textfile -separator "," -method split.by.hash -sourcetable test -sourcefieldnames "name, id" -targettable test_td -targetfieldnames "name, id"

I am getting below error even though I placed correct jar hive-common-1.1.0.jar in hive/lib path.

```
INFO tool.ConnectorImportTool: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.common.util.HiveStringUtils.normalizeIdentifier(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore$GetHelper.<init>(ObjectStore.java:2330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore$GetDbHelper.<init>(ObjectStore.java:2466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore$1.<init>(ObjectStore.java:555)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabaseInternal(ObjectStore.java:555)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:539)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:98)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:588)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:161)
        at com.teradata.connector.hive.utils.HiveUtils.isHiveOutputTablePartitioned(HiveUtils.java:1039)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.processArgs(ConnectorImportTool.java:607)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.run(ConnectorImportTool.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataImportTool.main(TeradataImportTool.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

15/05/14 06:16:54 INFO tool.ConnectorImportTool: job completed with exit code 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a version in which the method does not exists. Kindly check the version of the jar in which this method exists. You should have hive common 1.1.0 API dependency and if it exists then your module is picking a different version.